# PHP Referencing array from within itself inside a Closure member

Tags: php, arrays, closures, anonymous-function

I have an array with a Closure member, which gets called at a specific moment during execution and performs operations with the array's own members.

```
$a = [];

$a['const'] = 5;

$a['closure'] = function() {
    return ($a['const'] * 2);
};

print_r($a['closure']());
```

This gives

```
NOTICE Undefined variable: a on line number 6
0
```

I'm not sure why `$a` doesn't work as I have already defined it as a separate statement before the line that defines the Closure member. It seems I have no way of referencing the array from within itself that I'm aware of.

Can it be done?

Comment: Your function knows nothing about `$a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because you don't pass `$a` variable in the anonymous function. You can pass `$a` variable into a function with help inheriting variables from the parent scope (with usage `use` constuction). For example:

```
$a = [];
$a['const'] = 5;
$a['closure'] = function() use ($a){
    return ($a['const'] * 2);
};

print_r($a['closure']());
```

Answer (score 2):

Hope this below code will help you.

```
<?php

$a = [];

$a['const'] = 5;

$a['closure'] = function($a) {
    return ($a['const'] * 2);
};

print_r($a['closure']($a));
```